# React Navigation - Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to get my button in the header to navigate to a gallery of images. When I press the button, I get "Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined. Both of these files are in the same folder, which is "Profiles". Anybody know what this errors means and how to possibly fix it?

This is how I have the button set up in my headerRight.

```
//HomerSimpson.js    
import React from "react";
    import {
      Button,
      View,
      Text,
      StyleSheet,
      Image,
      List,
      ListItem,
      ImageBackground
    } from "react-native";

    import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';
    import HomerGallery from "./Profiles/HomerGallery";


    class HomerSimpson extends React.Component {
      static navigationOptions = {
        title: "Homer Simpson Profile",
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#53b4e6"
        },
        headerTintColor: "#f6c945",
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: "bold"
        },
        headerRight: (
          <Button
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("HomerGallery")}
            title="Gallery"
            color="#f6c945"
          />
        )
      };
```

I made a separate component for the gallery itself and it's in the same folder as HomerSimpson.js.

```
//HomerGallery.js
import React from "react";
    import {
      Button,
      View,
      Text,
      StyleSheet,
      Image,
      List,
      ListItem,
      ImageBackground
    } from "react-native";

    import ImageSlider from 'react-native-image-slider';


    class HomerGallery extends React.Component {
      static navigationOptions = {
        title: "Homer's Gallery",
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#53b4e6"
        },
        headerTintColor: "#f6c945",
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: "bold"
        },
        headerRight: <Button onPress={() => alert("Bart loves to skateboard")} title="Facts" color="#f6c945" />
      };
      render() {
        return (<ImageSlider images={[
          'https://i.pinimg.com/474x/f1/36/ca/f136ca04817e60fa12f4a5680101ff8b.jpg',
          'https://i.pinimg.com/474x/b1/da/e2/b1dae2fe6ca1620e5d1949a2dcd33a0c.jpg',
          'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/7b/53/32/7b5332ef6a981b3c54e855495ea1c828.jpg',
          'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/f4/71/79/f471798aeeae427474f544691d572970.jpg',
          'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/32/3d/53/323d534f07de7d9ebeb58ede1f87d63e.jpg'
        ]}/>)
      };
    }

    export default HomerGallery;
```

The route for the gallery is "HomerGallery". Here is how it's set up in my navigation file. It's imported, but I'll leave those il

```
    import HomerGallery from "../../Profiles/HomerGallery";
    import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";

    const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
      {
        Login: Login,
        Home: HomeScreen,
        Details: DetailsScreen,
        Bio: BioScreen,
        EmployeeDirectory: EmployeeDirectory,
        HomerSimpson: HomerSimpson,
        BartSimpson: BartSimpson,
        MargeSimpson: MargeSimpson,
        LisaSimpson: LisaSimpson,
        MaggieSimpson: MaggieSimpson,
        SantasHelper: SantasHelper,
        BarneyGumble: BarneyGumble,
        MrBurns: MrBurns,
        KentBrockman: KentBrockman,
        RalphWiggum: RalphWiggum,
        OttoMan: OttoMan,
        Scratchy: Scratchy,
        HomerGallery: HomerGallery,
        BallBounce: BallBounce,
        OverlayPage: OverlayPage, 
        Rankings: Rankings
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: "HomerSimpson",
        defaultNavigationOptions: {
            headerStyle: '#f4511e',
        },
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
        },
      },
    );

    export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Comment: It seems that you are not using withNavigation in your code. You should wrap HomeSimpson with withNavigation and then use it in the AppNavigator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the offending line `onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("HomerGallery")}`. The static object `navigationOptions` won't have access to `this.props` of the component.

You don't mention React Navigation, but I'm guessing that's what you're using. Here's an example from their docs that shows how you can access `props` by using a function instead of an object. Good luck!

```js
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      title: navigation.getParam('otherParam', 'A Nested Details Screen'),
    };
  }
```

**Update**

Example applied to your code:

```js
navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
  title: "Homer Simpson Profile",
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "#53b4e6"
  },
  headerTintColor: "#f6c945",
  headerTitleStyle: {
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
  headerRight: (
    <Button
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate("HomerGallery")}
      title="Gallery"
      color="#f6c945"
    />
  )
});
```

Comment: Just did! @Mohrn

Answer (score 2):

**HomerSimpson.js**

```
export default withNavigation(HomerSimpson)
```

This should pass all the necessary navigation props.